# SQL update based on hierarchial data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For each employee based on the manager it should pickup the department.

If the manager's department is `null` it should pickup his manager's department. This hierarchy loop should continue till it picks up some department. Please find attached image for the data or the below.

```
EmpName EmpId   MgrName MgrId   Dept
A         1        D      4 
B         2        D      4 
C         3        D      4 
D         4        E      5 
E         5        F      6 
F         6        G      7 
G         7        Q     17     CSC
H         8        I      9 
I         9        Q     17     MECH
J        10        O     15 
K        11        O     15 
L        12        O     15 
M        13        O     15 
N        14        O     15 
O        15        Q     17      EEE
P        16        Q     17 
Q        17                       IT
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sam.  Can i suggest you post the data in a format the users can cut and paste directly into an editor? You'll find you get better responses that way.  As a general hint, you can have a look at iterative cte's for navigating trees.

Comment: I would apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model to your table, otherwise would be hell. Sorry But I got interrupted while answering the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly update from a Recursive Query.

```
;with RCTE as
(
    select EmpId as RootEmpId, 0 as Lvl, EmpId, MgrID, Dept
    from Employee
    where Dept is null

    union all

    select r.RootEmpId, r.Lvl + 1, e.EmpId, e.MgrID, e.Dept
    from RCTE r
    join Employee e on e.EmpId = r.MgrID
    where r.Dept is null
) 
update e
set Dept = r.Dept
from Employee e 
join RCTE r on (e.EmpId = r.RootEmpId and r.Dept is not null)
where e.Dept is null;
```

**Example Test Snippet**

```
declare @Employee table (EmpId int primary key, EmpName nvarchar(100), MgrID int, Dept NVARCHAR(4));

insert into @Employee (EmpName, EmpId, MgrID, Dept) VALUES  
 ('A',1,4,null)
,('B',2,4,null)
,('C',3,4,null)
,('D',4,5,null)
,('E',5,6,null)
,('F',6,7,null)
,('G',7,17,'CSC')
,('H',8,9,null)
,('I',9,17,'MECH')
,('J',10,15,null)
,('K',11,15,null)
,('L',12,15,null)
,('M',13,15,null)
,('N',14,15,null)
,('O',15,17,'EEE')
,('P',16,17,null)
,('Q',17,null,'IT')
;

;with RCTE as
(
    select EmpId as RootEmpId, 0 as Lvl, EmpId, MgrID, Dept
    from @Employee
    where Dept is null

    union all

    select r.RootEmpId, r.Lvl + 1, e.EmpId, e.MgrID, e.Dept
    from RCTE r
    join @Employee e on e.EmpId = r.MgrID
    where r.Dept is null
) 
update e
set Dept = r.Dept
from @Employee e 
join RCTE r on (e.EmpId = r.RootEmpId and r.Dept is not null)
where e.Dept is null;

select 
 e.EmpName, e.EmpId, e.MgrID, e.Dept, 
 m.EmpName as MgrName, m.Dept as MgrDept
from @Employee e
join @Employee m on (m.EmpId = e.MgrID)
order by EmpId;
```

*Side note: In the spirit of [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) it would be more common pratice to maintain a Department table. And then just store a DepartmentID foreign key in the Customer table. Instead of the department name, which can change.*

Answer (score 0):

You can add the rest of your data to this and give it a try:

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE (EmpName NVARCHAR(1)
                        ,EmpId INT
                        ,MGRName NVARCHAR(1)
                        ,MgrID INT
                        ,Dept NVARCHAR(4)
                        )

INSERT  INTO @table
        (EmpName, EmpId, MGRName, MgrID, Dept)
VALUES  ('A', 1, 'D', 4, '')
,       ('B', 2, 'D', 4, '')
,       ('C', 3, 'D', 4, '')
,       ('D', 4, 'E', 5, '')
,       ('E', 5, 'F', 6, '')
,       ('F', 6, 'G', 7, '')
,       ('G', 7, 'Q', 17, 'CSC')
,       ('Q', 2, '', NULL, 'IT');
WITH    cte
          AS (SELECT    EmpName
              ,         EmpId
              ,         MGRName
              ,         MgrID
              ,         Dept
              FROM      @table t
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    c.EmpName
              ,         c.EmpId
              ,         t2.MGRName
              ,         t2.MgrID
              ,         t2.Dept
              FROM      @table t2
              JOIN      cte C ON c.MGRId = t2.EmpId
                AND c.Dept = ''
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
    WHERE Dept <> ''
    ORDER BY EMpName
```

For future questions if you supplied the table declare and sample data as something we can cut and paste you'll probably get more responses.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for the quick response. I have this table loaded in the database and I just need to update the department column. Could you please suggest the change in the above query ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it
You had denomalized data by including the mgr name

```
declare @t table (Emp char, Id int, MgrId int, Dept varchar(10))
insert @t values
('A',  1,    4,  null),
('B',  2,    4,  null), 
('C',  3,    4,  null), 
('D',  4,    5,  null), 
('E',  5,    6,  null), 
('F',  6,    7,  null), 
('G',  7,   17, 'CSC'),
('H',  8,    9,  null), 
('I',  9,   17, 'MCH'),
('J', 10,   15,  null), 
('K', 11,   15,  null), 
('L', 12,   15,  null), 
('M', 13,   15,  null), 
('N', 14,   15,  null), 
('O', 15,   17, 'EEE'),
('P', 16,   17,  null), 
('Q', 17, null, 'IT');
with cte as 
( select t1.Id, t1.emp, t1.MgrId, isnull(t1.Dept, t2.Dept) as Dept, t2.Emp as 'mgr', t2.MgrId as nextMgr 
    from @t t1
    left join @t t2 
      on t2.Id = t1.MgrId
    --where not exists ( select * from @t t where t.MgrId = t1.Id )
    union all 
    select t1.Id, t1.emp, t1.MgrId, t2.Dept, t1.mgr, t2.MgrId as nextMgr
    from cte t1  
    join @t t2 
      on t2.Id = t1.nextMgr
     and t1.Dept is null
)
select * 
from cte 
where Dept is not null
order by id

Id          emp  MgrId       Dept       mgr  nextMgr
----------- ---- ----------- ---------- ---- -----------
1           A    4           CSC        D    17
2           B    4           CSC        D    17
3           C    4           CSC        D    17
4           D    5           CSC        E    17
5           E    6           CSC        F    17
6           F    7           CSC        G    17
7           G    17          CSC        Q    NULL
8           H    9           MCH        I    17
9           I    17          MCH        Q    NULL
10          J    15          EEE        O    17
11          K    15          EEE        O    17
12          L    15          EEE        O    17
13          M    15          EEE        O    17
14          N    15          EEE        O    17
15          O    17          EEE        Q    NULL
16          P    17          IT         Q    NULL
17          Q    NULL        IT         NULL NULL
```